# Publish a Post on a Future Date Automtically

Tags: posts

I would like to give my user the ability to publish a post and the post only becomes visible  (like with a published status) when the date hits. I'm using the following code to try and set it to published but on a future date:

```
$bmt_post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
    'post_content'  => $information,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array( $cat_ids ),
    'post_date_gmt' => $postdate,
    'post_date' => $postdate,
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $bmt_post );
```

When I do this, the post is already visible even though it's scheduled for a future date. If I remove the `'post_status'   => 'publish'` then it creates the post as a draft but then someone would have to go back on the date and change the status from draft to published.

How can I do this so when the user creates the post it's created for the future and only becomes visible when the post_date is the actual date? I know there is a `'post_status'   => 'future'` but does that automatically convert to published on that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From digging through /wp-includes/post.php, it looks like you may need to do the following:

1. set your post_status to future
2. set the post_date to when you want it published
3. insert the post as your code shows

Run the following code after inserting the post

```
$time = strtotime( $postdate . ' GMT' );
wp_schedule_single_event( $time, 'publish_future_post', array( $post_id ) );
```

That is what wordpress uses internally to schedule future posts. check the following function for more information

```
check_and_publish_future_post( $post_id )
```